# How do I call a Content Block into an Email built with Content Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder, content-area

I am trying to call content stored in a Content Block into an email in Content Builder, but am receiving the follwoing error:

*The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.
An error occurred when attempting to evaluate an ContentArea function call.
 Function Call: ContentArea('435195')
 See inner exception for details.
The specified content area client does not match the job client.
 ContentAreaID: 435195
 Job ClientID: 1433232
 Content ClientID: 1371193
 Function Name: ContentArea
 Parameter Name: ContentID
 Parameter Ordinal: 1
 Parameter Type: Numeric
 Submitted Value: 435195
 ClientID: 1433232
 JobID: 0
 ListID: 0
 BatchID: 0
 SubcriberID: 0
 Data Source Type: CustomObject
 Data Source ID: cee6f51b-02c6-e611-aa2c-78e3b50cb244*

This code works just fine when calling content from Email Classic/ Classic Editor. What do I need to do differently to achieve the same outcome in Content Builer?

Here is the code I have currently:

```
<br><i>%%[VAR @Email, @FName, @LName, @Exp, @Points, @DOB, @Level
<br>SET @Email=Email
<br>SET @FName=FirstName
<br>SET @LName=LastName
<br>SET @Exp=LoyaltyExp
<br>SET @Points=LoyaltyPoints
<br>SET @DOB=DOB
<br>SET @Level=Level]%%<br>
<br> %%[IF NOT EMPTY (@Email) THEN]%%<br>
%%=ContentArea('718820')=%%<br>
%%[ENDIF]%%</i>
```

Comment: I can't read the text in that image. Can you [edit] your question to include the text of the error message, instead of an image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For content stored inside of ContentBuilder, you will need to use the 'new' AMPscript functions.  Not sure on the details of why, but in building Content Builder / Email Studio, they completely removed the storage location from the previous Portfolio section.  The bad thing about this is that a lot of options that previously worked, no longer work on Content Builder stuff.

To answer your question you will need to use either:

[ContentBlockByID](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/contentblockbyid6/) (`%%=ContentBlockbyID("384201")=%%`)

or

[ContentBlockByKey](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/contentblockbykey/) (`%%=ContentBlockbyKey("myContentBlock")=%%`)

You should be able to find both of these easily inside the properties field of the content area.